# Check constraint for column in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, check-constraint

I need to create a table, where the values of column "`ttime`" can be within the range of `10:00` and `22:00`. Here' the code:

```
create table test (    
  ttime date,
  CONSTRAINT CHECK_ttime CHECK(ttime >= TO_DATE('10:00', 'HH24:MI') AND
                               ttime <= TO_DATE('22:00', 'HH24:MI'))
);
```

But when I create this table, an error occurs:

> ORA-02436: date or system variable wrongly specified in CHECK
>   constraint

How can I avoid it? What's the problem?

Answer (score 3):

To enforce such a constraint you need to extract time from `ttime` column. When you convert a time portion of a date(represented as a string literal here `'10:00'`) to a value of `DATE` data type the date portion defaults to the first day of the current month and year, thus `TO_DATE('10:00', 'HH24:MI')` will result in `01/05/2017 10:00:00` and your condition becomes

```
ttime >= 01/05/2017 10:00:00 and  ttime <= 01/05/2017 22:00:00
```

Note: `AND` should be replaced by `OR`. `ttime` cannot be less than some value and at the same time be greater than the same value.

Having said that, as one of the options, you can define your constrains as follows:

```
constraint t1_chk01 check (to_number(to_char(c1, 'HH24MI')) 
                           between 1000 and 2200)
```